# Setting header label text indentation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am working on a Customized tableview with header text label.  In tableview delegate method viewForHeaderInSection I am setting

```
CGFloat indentWidth = 0.7f;
CGRect frame = headerLabel.frame;
frame.origin.x = indentWidth;
headerLabel.frame = frame;
```

This is not working and header label is still stuck to the tableview border. I tried to change the indentWidth but it is not working that way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Retagged.

Comment: Are you returning `headerLabel` as the header view?  Or is it a subview of the view you're returning?

Comment: Also, 0.7 points is a pretty small amount of indentation.  You might not be able to notice it easily.  Try 70 and see if it's noticeable.

Comment: Yes. I am returning headerLabel as the header view. and i already tried setting indentWidth unto 500.0f but did not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake( put new rect here );
```

Comment: Thanks w770115. i got the solution by referring to this example [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) but you are correct in a way. :)